# Luxon me devuelve un dia de menos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, datetime

Seguí las instrucciones de instalación de `luxon` incluyendo `full-icu`

```
npm -i luxon
npm install full-icu
```

Y corro mi versión de desarrollo de esta manera:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node --icu-data-dir=./node_modules/full-icu app.js ",
    "start-local": "nodemon --icu-data-dir=./node_modules/full-icu app.js "
  },
```

Pero al obtener la fecha de hoy y mostrarla me da un día menos.

```
  query.fechaLimiteSuperior = DateTime.fromJSDate(
      query.fechaLimiteSuperior
        ? new Date(query.fechaLimiteSuperior)
        //Provoco que entre aqui al no definir fechaLimiteSuperior
        : new Date(`${anio}-${mes}-${dia}`)
    )



console.log(${query.fechaLimiteInferior.toFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")} 
//Deberia devolver 20-11-2020 pero devuelve 19-11-2020
```

Este es el objeto que imprime luxon:

```
query.fechaLimiteInferior DateTime {
  ts: 1605916800000,
  _zone: LocalZone {},
  loc: Locale {
    locale: 'es-MX',
    numberingSystem: null,
    outputCalendar: null,
    intl: 'es-MX',
    weekdaysCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
    monthsCache: { format: {}, standalone: {} },
    meridiemCache: null,
    eraCache: {},
    specifiedLocale: null,
    fastNumbersCached: null
  },
  invalid: null,
  weekData: null,
  c: {
    year: 2020,
    month: 11,
    day: 20,
    hour: 18,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0,
    millisecond: 0
  },
  o: -360,
  isLuxonDateTime: true
}
```

Que es lo que estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: debe ser por la zona horaria

Comment: Creo que si, pero no he podido resolver eso.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar poniendo la zona horaria

```
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const d = DateTime.fromISO(yourDate, {zone: 'America/New York'});
console.log(d.toISO());
```